# Accessing file from the Windows host in a VirtualBox virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, files, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 as the guest operating system in a VirtualBox virtual machine. The host runs Windows 8 (24GB). I want to access a folder of the host inside the guest.

Since the source is huge, I am trying to use it directly from Windows and mount it on the guest system.

I searched online, and installed `virtualboximage.iso` and shared my folder in windows 8 in the settings of VirtualBox (basic steps). 
I checked for my shared folder under `/mnt` folder but it is empty.

How can I access the folder from Windows 8 to the guest system?

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember the share is in `/media`.

More importantly, I could not get it to auto mount the first time, so had to manual mount. A reboot of the guest also does the mount. I think the share is also done via smb, so I think it is accessible via network share immediately, and automatically.

—

Sorry I don't have a system to test, this is all from memory.